# Timber/Twig define Block

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm new to [Timber](http://jarednova.github.io/timber/)/[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), but so far I'm loving it!

I would like to have a folder with partials/components or "blocks" as Timber/Twig calls them, so I could have say a "video.twig" component, that can be reused through out the page.

1) How can I "register" the components/block in a folder?

2) How can I "feed" the component/block with data? I would like to do something like this:

```
{% block component DATA %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in `include` looks like this:

```
{% include "comment.twig" with {comment:cmt} %}
```

It may work for the block too. Give it a shot.

Comment: Great m8, just what was looking for. Thanks!